# How to convert a negative number to positive?

Tags: python, numbers, absolute-value

How can I convert a negative number to positive in Python? (And keep a positive one.)

Comment: Reading the original question (or the return to the original phrasing if [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10741589) gets approved), it's unclear what your parenthesized sentence was supposed to mean. Did you mean you wanted to keep a copy of the original, or did you mean that you wanted to leave positive values unmodified?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

```
>>> n = -42
>>> -n       # if you know n is negative
42
>>> abs(n)   # for any n
42
```

Don't forget to check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#abs).

Comment: There's also `max(n, -n)` (just another alternative :)

Comment: `max` is a neat trick, but, especially in python, there is an overhead to it, which will be 30% slower than `abs`. So you should definitely prefer `abs` over `max`

Comment: you have to store it in a variable you know...(I got a huge mess because of that!!!!)

Answer (score 91):

simply multiplying by -1 works in both ways ...

```
>>> -10 * -1
10
>>> 10 * -1
-10
```

Comment: This would be the simplest solution I guess. This solution would convert negative to positive and positive to negative number.

Comment: Classical math.

Answer (score 44):

If **"keep a positive one"** means you want a positive number to stay positive, but also convert a negative number to positive, use `abs()`:

```
>>> abs(-1)
1
>>> abs(1)
1
```

Answer (score 17):

The inbuilt function abs() would do the trick.

```
positivenum = abs(negativenum)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are working with numpy you can use

```
import numpy as np
np.abs(-1.23)
>> 1.23
```

It will provide absolute values.

Comment: While true, I can't think of a situation in which this would be preferred to Python's native `abs` function.

Answer (score 7):

```
In [6]: x = -2
In [7]: x
Out[7]: -2

In [8]: abs(x)
Out[8]: 2
```

Actually `abs` will return the `absolute value` of any number. Absolute value is always a non-negative number.

Comment: Does abs(0) return a positive number? :)

Answer (score 0):

The inbuilt function abs() would do the trick.

```
n = -42
abs(n)   # for any n
42
```