# How to find absolute value of elements in an array?

Tags: python-3.x

```
I have an array containing some negative values. how can i find the absolute value?
```

for eg suppose my array is

```
arr = [-2,-5,0,1,2]
```

and i want an array

`arr_out =[2,5,0,1,2]`

Comment: You can created new Array from older array and convert negative values to positive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854310/how-to-convert-a-negative-number-to-positive

Answer (score 1):

Without `numpy` using list comprehension:

```
arr = [-2,-5,0,1,2]
arr_out = [abs(i) for i in arr]

print(arr_out)
```

Output:

> [2, 5, 0, 1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr = [-2,-5,0,1,2] 

print("Absolute value: ", np.absolute(arr))
```